# updating DATETIME causes sqlite error on BB10

Tags: c++, sqlite, sql-update, blackberry-10, datetime2

I created my table with this query

```
CREATE TABLE SETTINGS(NAME VARCHAR(1050), VALUE VARCHAR(1550),CREATE_DATE_TIME DATETIME,UPDATE_DATE_TIME DATETIME, PRIMARY KEY(NAME))
```

Then I inserted data like this

```
INSERT INTO SETTINGS(NAME, VALUE ,CREATE_DATE_TIME ,UPDATE_DATE_TIME) VALUES('CellIDKey','Android@MoblLe.NAv',DATETIME('NOW'), DATETIME('NOW'))
```

At this point it works fine. Now if I want to run an update query like this,

```
UPDATE SETTINGS SET VALUE='Android@AfriG1s.MoblLe.NAv' CREATE_DATE_TIME=DATETIME('NOW')  WHERE NAME='CellIDKey'
```

It shows the following error on console

```
QSqlError::type= "QSqlError::ConnectionError" , QSqlError::number= -1 , databaseText= "No query" , driverText= "Unable to fetch row"
```

But if I run this update query like this,

```
UPDATE SETTINGS SET VALUE='Android@AfriG1s.MoblLe.NAv' WHERE NAME='CellIDKey'
```

Now it works fine. I don't know what is wrong with the DATETIME('NOW') statement on update query.

Comment: What is the exact query that you're trying to run? Or are you really missing a comma in your UPDATE's SET clause?

Comment: I just didn't put an ';' at the end of those statements. sqlite doesn't need that to run the query. They are the complete statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid SQL:

```
UPDATE SETTINGS SET VALUE='Android@AfriG1s.MoblLe.NAv' CREATE_DATE_TIME=DATETIME('NOW')  WHERE NAME='CellIDKey'
-- ---------------------------------------------------^ Missing comma!
```

The individual assignments in a SET need to be separated by commas like this:

```
UPDATE SETTINGS
SET VALUE='Android@AfriG1s.MoblLe.NAv', -- This comma is needed
    CREATE_DATE_TIME=DATETIME('NOW')
WHERE NAME='CellIDKey'
```